# Trying to test a ListIterator but it goes into an infinite loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop, listiterator

I am programming in Java I have created a class to obtain one iterator since I'm only using one list in this program with this code

```
public ListIterator<T> iterateur() {
    ListIterator<T> it = liste.listIterator();
    return it;
}
```

And then I try to use it with this method

```
public int ObtenirNbElments(int priorite) {
    int nbPrio=0;
    while(this.iterateur().hasNext()){
        if(this.iterateur().next().obtenirPriorite() == priorite){
            nbPrio++;
        }
    }
    return nbPrio;
}
```

Whenever I use it with my test class as such:

```
    listePriorite.ajouter(elt1);
    listePriorite.ajouter(elt2);
    listePriorite.ajouter(elt3);
    listePriorite.ajouter(elt4);
    listePriorite.ajouter(eltd1);
    assertEquals(2,listePriorite.ObtenirNbElments(1));
```

It seems to enter into an infinite loop why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you invoke `iterateur()` you create and return a new `ListIterator`. Call the method only once and store the result. Re-use the same object.

```
int nbPrio=0;
ListIterator<T> it = this.iterateur();
while(it.hasNext()){
    if(it.next().obtenirPriorite() == priorite){
        nbPrio++;
    }
}
return nbPrio;
```

(I'm assuming your `T` has bounds that make sense with `obtenirPriorite()`.)